# Publish our product on the AWS marketplace

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for some advice about a new AWS marketplace offering that we are working on.

We want to offer our product on the AWS marketplace via a CloudFormation template. The thing is, we are using Single AMI with CloudFormation Product Form, and we have uploaded this Form via a File upload. It more than 5 working days. It is not moved to another stage. We are confused that we have followed the right approach or not to publish our offer.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Our experience with Marketplace is, it takes at least 2 to 3 weeks to move from one phase to another. If you are in rush, try to create a support ticket. Good luck!